# Regex to capture TEST[some text] separately

Tags: regex, parsing, text, configuration, yaml

Struggling to create the regex to capture this:

```
TEST[some text]
```

and these:

```
TEST[some text]    |    TEST[some text]     |    TEST[some text]
```

but to capture the last group as 3 separate items.

I got as far as `/([A-Z]+\[.+\])/g` but that captures the line above as 1 item.

It also doesn't capture nested items like:

```
A[
  B[text]
  More text.
  C[and some more text]
]
```

Effectively I want to capture `A` (and its associated values within the brackets), `B` (and its values), `More text.`, and `C` (and its values) separately.

Basically the structure goes like:

```
KEY[VALUE]
```

and `VALUES` can consist of more KEY/VALUE pairs.

Perhaps there's some more generic way of creating / parsing these text structures (i.e. like a YAML file) that I'm not aware of. Any suggestions?

Sorry for the rather rambling and open-ended question.

Comment: Please read the first bullet of [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290740/3764814) - what regex *flavor* do you want to use?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is flavors to take into consideration, but what you're looking for can be done without too much flavor specific stuff

```
/([A-Z]+\[[^\]]+\])/g
```

Since `[^\]]+` will match any non-"]" character, you won't get nested ones. BUT, it wont match the **A** one from your examples, but I guess thats not needed either?